# i want to change url with using RewriteRule in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i want to change url:
http://www.localhost/mysqlimport/list.php?name=EXIM-PRIVATE-solution
with

http://www.localhost/mysqlimport/list/EXIM-PRIVATE-solution

with .htaccess file inside write rewriteRule
but how can i change link and page css and other link change in pages..

help me to solve this problem

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your best effort so we can help you on your way. To improve your chances of getting the answer you are looking for, read [ask]

Comment: i want to show url : http://www.localhost/mysqlimport/list/EXIM-PRIVATE-solution  like that for easy to read and .. when i change url my css  code facing effect .. not working

Answer (score 0):

Add in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(list)?$ list.php
RewriteRule ^(list/)?$ list.php
```

Then SET rules for list page in .htaccess

```
   #List page Rules
   RewriteRule ^(list/([A-Za-z0-9-,!@#$%^&*()+{}|::;?><~`'./\*+_]+))$ list.php?page_name=$1&name=$2
   RewriteRule ^(list/([A-Za-z0-9-,!@#$%^&*()+{}|::;?><~`'./\*+_]+)/)$ list.php?page_name=$1&name=$2
```

Use `$_GET['name']` on list.php to get your parameter "EXIM-PRIVATE-solution"

**Note: Use filter when getting data on page**

Use `<base href="http://www.localhost/mysqlimport/">` in head of html page on front-end

Comment: thanku for help .. but i already get answer..